# Futurebuilder connectionState.done returning true, even though my data is not yet ready and returning null. Wont rebuild after data available

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-futurebuilder, stream-builder

I've been trying to figure this out so far with no luck.

I have a streambuilder which pulls the user's closest 8 locations like this:

```
Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream() =>
geo.collection(collectionRef: ref).within(center: center, radius: radius, field: 'position').take(1);
```

Here is the streambuilder which returns those 8 locations as a list, and builds its own list of cards based on this data:

```
    StreamBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
  stream: _stream,
  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.data != null) {
      List<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>? streamList = snapshot.data?.toList();
        for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        print(i);
        var tester = streamList![i].id;
        varX.add(streamList![i]['xxx']);
        Test.add(tester);
        listNearby = List<String>.from(Test);
        
          if (i == 7) {
              Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
              getFuture;
              });
           alreadyBuilt = 1;
          }
        }

      return SizedBox(///Here I display some information from that stream);
    } else {
        return SizedBox(///Here I display the loading information);
    }
}),
```

So then this returns a 'listNearby', I use this list to pull 8 other document ID's in a different firebase database in the following manner: Some of the issues I'm having - I'm not sure what the correct way to wait for the listNearby to be completed/returned from my futureStream.

```
Future pullData() async {
  if (listNearby.isNotEmpty) {
    var listNearbyReturn = [];
    var firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      DocumentSnapshot gG = await firestore.collection('xxxx').doc(listNearby[i]).get();
      listTest.add(gG.data().toString());
      try {
        for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
          ///I pull specific data I need from the snapshot.
          final incremDt = _now.add(Duration(days: x));
          final incremDtFrmtd = DateFormat('MM-dd-yyyy').format(incremDt);
          var regexp = RegExp(r"(?<=xx-).+?(?=:)");
          Iterable<Match> matches = regexp.allMatches(gG.get(incremDtFrmtd).toString(), 0);
          if (matches.isNotEmpty) {
            for (final Match h in matches) {
              ///other calculations
              listNearbyReturn.add({///Add some variables which I need to show a future card
                });
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
    listNearbyReturn((a, b) {
      int dateComp = a['date'].compareTo!(b['date']);
      if (dateComp == 0) {
        return parseTime(a['time'][0]).compareTo(parseTime((b['time'][0])));
      }
      return dateComp;
    });
    print('done');
    print(listNearbyReturn);
    return listNearbyReturn;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

This returns to my futurebuilder which can be seen below, although I'm having all sorts of issues. The ConnectionState.done is showing true/connected although the snapshot.data is still null, shouldn't it wait for a non-null response?

```
FutureBuilder(
future: getFuture,
builder: (_, snapshot) {
print(snapshot.data);
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    print('connected');
    print('are we seeing null here? ${snapshot.data}'); //<==== YES, it is showing null? Why? It shouldn't connect until data is non null
return Container(
   height: 150,
    child: ListView.separated(///Here I build my listview),
);
}

if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
    print('waiting');
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
} else
    print('failed?');
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
});
)
```

I am initializing my futurebuilder in the following manner (at least for now, it has changed so much over the past few days)

```
class _HomescreenState extends State<FinderHomescreen> {
  late Future getFuture;
  final _stream = stream();


  @override
  void initState() {
    getGames();
    getFuture = pullData();
    super.initState();
  }
```

So there are a few questions throughout here, some to confirm my understanding, some to see if I am missing something obvious. My overall question is the following: I need my streambuilder to return 8 closest locations to the user, those locations are then fed to a list which will be iterated through to pull from a different firebase database to pull different information based on those 8 locations (but stored elsewhere). This is causing my futurebuilder to accept 'null' as a response and build with null and never rebuild once the data becomes actually available (only a hot reload will load my cards). What is the correct way to accomplish this? I have also tried using provider but this creates an infinite reload loop as the data is recollected, and the widget is rebuilt - rebuilding the tree etc...

Comment: 1. It's very hard to read your code without formatting.  You seem to have discarded most of your indentation. 2. What is `if (i == 7) { Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async { getFuture; });` supposed to do?  It doesn't do anything. 3. Is your intention that `pullData` checks a `listNearby.isNotEmpty` where `listNearby` is presumably a member variable, but then it declares its own *local* `listNearby` variable?

Comment: 4. The local `listNearby` variable is initialized to an empty `List`, but then you promptly attempt to dereference the first 8 elements, which should immediately throw a `RangeError`.  You then swallow that with `catch (e)` (and you should [avoid such blanket `catch` clauses](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-catches-without-on-clauses)).

Comment: @jamesdlin I really appreciate you help here, thank you! 1. Sorry, I will try fixing that up! 2. I was trying to reinitialize the pullData() since the data wasn't available until this would get to 7, it's not working though. 3. Yes, sorry - I changed things up to simplify the code to paste into here and I unintelligently named those the same thing.. They are actually different variables in my code. I have changed it in my pasted code!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into something like this, I had to change the logic as to how I was sending my 8 closest locations to my futurebuilder list:

Instead of returning a list 'listNearby' within my streambuilder, I created a new future:

```
Future<List<DocumentSnapshot>> getClosestLocations() async {
  List<DocumentSnapshot> closestLocations = [];
  await for (List<DocumentSnapshot> documents in stream()) {
    closestLocations = documents;
    break;
  }
  return closestLocations;
}
```

Then within my pullData:

```
    List<DocumentSnapshot> closestLocations = await getClosestLocations();
```

Then I iterate though that one.